# What is the CSS equivalent for the style of this table?

Tags: html, css

I really would like to use the layout of this table, but how can I bring this up to CSS standards of its equivalent into HTML5?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting that there's a `style="background-color:#ffffff"` in lieu of `bgcolor="#ffffff"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table {
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-spacing: 1px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}

table td {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: What about the `cellspacing`?

Comment: cellspacing: table td {margin: 1px;}

Comment: In short: for non-IE 5-7 browsers, border-spacing handles you. For IE, if your situation is just right (you want 0 cellspacing and your table doesn't have it defined already), you can use border-collapse:collapse.

table { 
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a .css file then link to that from your HTML page using  tag

Give your table an id="mytable"

```
#mytable {
background-color:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #000000;
width:100%;
}

#mytable td {
padding:3px;
}
```

was editing and then saw other posters reply. so yep he has it nailed down.